# Connect to Dynamics Database through Python and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, dynamics-crm, etl, microsoft-dynamics

I'm new to dynamics but don't understand why I need to pay for a connector into my database.
Is it possible to do the [following link](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/dynamicscrm-python-sqlalchemy.rst) for free?

I tried looking online and alternative packages and options, only to find there is a cost for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to pay for a third party connector, you can use the APIs Dataverse/Dynamics offers.

The APIs are based on OData 4.0 (documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/overview))

If you need to build requests you can use my tool [Dataverse REST Builder](https://github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB), you can export the collection to Postman and generate the Python code from there.

Comment: This is helpful Guido, I may contact you separately unless you know if through the above it is possible to perform an ETL pipeline pushing to Dynamics database (dataverse?)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely agree that the oData APIs are the way to go here. I've built a simple Python program for connecting to Dataverse data in Python for data download/analysis. It uses interactive logins but the same principles can be used to interact with Dataverse as a database.

Blog: https://andyhowes.co/easily-connect-to-dataverse-microsoft-dynamics-with-python/

Code: https://github.com/YesWeCandrew/PyConnectDataverse

The other option is to pay for a connector, the benefit being that they've likely already have done the hard-work of mapping common CRUD operations to API queries making it easier for you to develop quickly.